# Android - Delete an item from ListViewAdapter and then Refresh

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to delete an item from my ListViewAdapter, I've implemented my `setOnItemLongClickListener` doing this :

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On long click listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                return true;
                            }
                        });
```

It shows me a Toast, verifying that it detects the `onClickListener`, I try to remove it doing : `mItems.remove(arg2);`, but nothing happens... I was looking for the correct answer and I found that I had to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but since I couldn't call this method I tried this one :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.ofertasRefresh:
            mItems.notifyAll();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

but nothing happens, no error on LogCat, no app crashes, no nothing... Can you guys tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Try out `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: You have to notifydatasetchanged on the adapter of the  listview

Comment: I have this at the end of my ListView `setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));`

Comment: then add this `ListViewDemoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do like this-

// as class member

```
ListViewDemoAdapter myAdapter;
```

then in the method-

```
myAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

now in the onItemClickListener,

```
mItems.remove(arg2);
myAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
setListAdapter(myAdapter);
```

note that, this is not the best solution, but it should work just fine for your case.

Comment: Why isn't the best solution?

Comment: as you are setting another new adapter object there might be some performance catch. As you have custom Adapter, you could write a public method of yours to remove the item from your datasource there and then just do like this-
myAdapter.removeFromMySource(arg2); // this is your own public method in your custom adapter
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
this would be the best solution.

Comment: my posted answer would be regarded as the best solution by many others but I beg to differ :). See my last comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to store your adapter in a member variable so that you can access it again later.

Instead of calling `setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));`, change your Fragment to look something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    private Adapter mListAdapter;

    @Override
    public voidonCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mListAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
        setListAdapter(mListAdapter);
    }

}
```

Then when you remove an item, you can call `mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so the list knows it needs to redraw.

[`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) isn't remotely close to [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

Comment: mAdapter is `ListViewDemoAdapter mAdapter;`?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. That should be the `mListAdapter` defined at the top of the Fragment. Fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your adapter global in your activity like this:

```
ListViewDemoAdapter adapter;
```

Put:

`adapter =  new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
setListAdapter(adapter);`

instead of:

`setListAdapter(new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));`

and when your removed item, you should call:

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: if you call in the onLongClick event this:  mItems.remove(arg2);
myAdapter = new ListViewDemoAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
setListAdapter(myAdapter); like @Amit K. Saha says, i think you recreate the listview each event, even if its not necessary. With notifyDataSetChanged() the adapter handler that.